# JS,как убрать класс selected после нажатия на всю карточку и после того как курсор ушел с карты

Tags: javascript

```js
function addClickListener(card) {
  card.addEventListener('click', function() {
    this.classList.remove('selected');
  });

  var button = card.querySelector('.myBtn');
  button.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    card.classList.add('selected');

    e.stopPropagation();
  });
}

var cards = document.querySelectorAll('.content1');
for (var i = 0; i < cards.length; i++) {
  addClickListener(cards[i]);
}
```

```html
<div class="content1">
  <div class="vector">
    <p> Лучшая <br> цена </p>
    <img src="img/vector.png" height="60px" width="60px" class="vector-img">

  </div>
  <img src="img/test2.jpg" alt="" class="content-img">
  <div class="content">

    <p class="header">
      Дуплекс
    </p>
    <p class="text">
      Просторный двухкомнатный <br> номер с шикарным видом на парк
    </p>
    <hr>
    <p class="price">
      от <span class="price1">5700</span> руб./сутки
    </p>
    <button class="myBtn">Забронировать</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

При нажатии на кнопку, карточка становиться selected. При нажатии на всю карточку класс selected снимается. Как сделать чтобы класс удалялся, после нажатия на всю карточку и ухода курсора с карточки. Не понимаю как совместить click и mouseleave .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например, можно придумать что-то такое :

```js
const div = document.querySelector('div.not-selected')
document.querySelector('input[type="button"]').addEventListener('click', e => div.classList.add('selected'))

div.addEventListener('click', e => e.target.dataset.clicked = 1)
div.addEventListener('mouseleave', e => {
  if (+e.target.dataset.clicked === 1) {
    e.target.dataset.clicked = 0
    div.classList.remove('selected')
  }
})
```

```css
.not-selected {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: blue;
}

.selected {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="not-selected"></div>
<input type="button" value="select" />
```

Замените `target` на `currentTarget`

```js
const div = document.querySelector('.content1')

document
  .querySelector('.myBtn')
  .addEventListener('click', e => div.classList.add('selected'))

div.addEventListener('click', e => e.currentTarget.dataset.clicked = 1)

div.addEventListener('mouseleave', e => {
  if (+e.target.dataset.clicked === 1) {
    e.target.dataset.clicked = 0
    div.classList.remove('selected')
  }
})
```

```css
.selected {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="content1">
  <div class="vector">
    <p> Лучшая <br> цена </p>
    <img src="img/vector.png" height="60px" width="60px" class="vector-img">

  </div>
  <img src="img/test2.jpg" alt="" class="content-img">
  <div class="content">

    <p class="header">
      Дуплекс
    </p>
    <p class="text">
      Просторный двухкомнатный <br> номер с шикарным видом на парк
    </p>
    <hr>
    <p class="price">
      от <span class="price1">5700</span> руб./сутки
    </p>
    <button class="myBtn">Забронировать</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: не подумал что не добавил html

Comment: окей, и в чем проблема сделать то же только с вашей разметкой ?)

Comment: я в самом начале пути, поэтому пока что все вызывает трудности . Ваш код работает только выбор карточки , а на снятие класса selected не работает

Comment: @damcha покажите как ви его применили

Comment: `const div = document.querySelector('.content1')
document.querySelector('.myBtn').addEventListener('click', e => div.classList.add('selected'))

div.addEventListener('click', e => e.target.dataset.clicked = 1)
div.addEventListener('mouseleave', e => {
  if (+e.target.dataset.clicked === 1) {
    e.target.dataset.clicked = 0
    div.classList.remove('selected')
  }
})`

Answer (score 0):

```
[...document.querySelectorAll('.content1')].forEach(card => {
  card.addEventListener('click', e => e.currentTarget.classList.toggle('selected'));
  card.addEventListener('mouseleave', e => e.currentTarget.classList.remove('selected'));
});
```

Comment: нужно чтобы работало сначала на нажатие всей карточки , а потом только на курсор , а не по отдельности или то или другое